# Have difficulty in pronouncing /g/

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, consonants

I noticed myself have this problem recently. When I pronounce /g/, I get a result like a mix of /g/ and /d/, is there any suggestions on how to train and improve this point?
I can hear the sound correctly, but I can not pronounce it well.

Comment: Anxious to answer but we need some examples of words you are working on and how they sound with /d/ or /g/ in order to assist.

Comment: Are you a native speaker or a learner? There is an English Language Learners' StackExchange where people may have more experience of learning the sounds. It seems that your problem might be that you need to keep the tip of your tongue down when saying /g/, or you might be pronouncing it too far forward in your mouth, but it's hard to say which is the case. It might also help to say what your native language is (if not English), and if you seem to be pronouncing it like a sound from that language.